# ND on a function using NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, function-construction

I need to numerically differentiate a function that takes a list as an argument and that uses `NIntegrate` in its definition. A simple example is

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

f[x_] := NIntegrate[Cos[(x[[1]] + x[[2]]) y], {y, 0, 1}];
ND[f[{1, 0} x], x, 1]
```

which returns the non-numerical value warning. I tried

```
f[x_?NUmericQ] := NIntegrate[Cos[(x[[1]] + x[[2]]) y], {y, 0, 1}];
```

but this does not evaluate either. Any ideas?

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO ANSWER**

What if `f` is redefined as

```
f[x_, u_] := NIntegrate[Cos[(x[[1]] + x[[2]] + u) y], {y, 0, 1}];
```

where u is a scalar and we wish to evaluate expressions like

```
ND[f[{1, 0} x, 3], x, 1]
```

and

```
ND[f[{1, 1}, u], u, 1]
```

I tried:

```
f[x_, u_] /; VectorQ[x, NumericQ] && NumericQ[u] :=
NIntegrate[Cos[(x[[1]] + x[[2]] + u) y], {y, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Could you check your new examples for correctness? In principle it seems to me that you should be able to define `f[x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ]&), u?NumericQ] := ...` if you want $x$ to be a vector of numerical quantities, and $u$ a numerical scalar. But then if everything is numerical, `f` will simply return a scalar, so what should `ND` do with that then?

Comment: @MarcoB your suggestion does the job. Cheers...

Answer (score 2):

Define it instead as

```
f[x_] /; VectorQ[x, NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Cos[(x[[1]] + x[[2]]) y], {y, 0, 1}]
```

so that it only explicitly works on a list of numerical values.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this approach. To get a better understanding I have extended my original question to cover the case where the function f takes both a list and a scalar as arguments. What can be done in this case?