# Extract solutions of linear system to variables

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, linear-algebra

I need to output the answers from solve into the variables named just as they were named in the solve equations. I have checked out this thread

[Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables)

but this is more about one variable having different values being stored. So you extract one data at a time and all. What I want is basically have the output of this solve below stored to the variables i1, i2, i3 and i4 so I can use them in further calculations.

```
In: Solve[-I (i2 - i1) + 5 (i2 - i4) + I (i2 - i3) == 0 && I (i3 - i2) + i3 == 0 && 5 (i4 - i2) + 1 + I == 0 && i1 + 2 == 0, {i1, i2, i3, i4}]

Out: {{i1 -> -2, i2 -> -2, i3 -> -1 - I, i4 -> -(11/5) - I/5}}
```

I tried something like

```
{i1, i2, i3, i4} -> {-2, -2, -1 - I, -(11/5) - I/5}
```

but then

```
in: I (i1 - i3)
out: I (i1 - i3)
```

is what I got. The capital I are basically the imaginary operator but it becomes that when I copy paste here.

PS. I am not using linear solvers here or, better yet, MATLAB because I don't want to go through the troublesome arithmetics of simplification to get the coefficients.

Comment: If you are *very certain* that you obtain only one set of solutions from `Solve`, then you could use `Solve[youreqautions, yourvariables] /. Rule -> Set`. This will turn the list of rules returned by `Solve` into a list of assignments to the variables. Note that once those variables have values assigned, your `Solve` expression will no longer work until the values are cleared. Again, I really would **not** recommend using this: you should rather save the solutions / rules returned by `Solve` and apply them whenever you need to inject the variable values in expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is something like this

`sols = First[Solve[-I (i2 - i1) + 5 (i2 - i4) + I (i2 - i3) == 0 && I (i3 - i2) + i3 == 0 && 5 (i4 - i2) + 1 + I == 0 && i1 + 2 == 0, {i1, i2, i3, i4}]];`

`{i1, i2, i3, i4} /. sols`

to extract the required solutions.

If as you say you "don't want to go through the troublesome arithmetics of simplification to get the coefficients", then here is something for you:

`eqns= {-I (i2 - i1) + 5 (i2 - i4) + I (i2 - i3) == 0 , I (i3 - i2) + i3 == 0 , 5 (i4 - i2) + 1 + I == 0 , i1 + 2 == 0};`

`{b, A} = Normal[CoefficientArrays[Subtract @@@ eqns, {i1, i2, i3, i4}]]`

`LinearSolve[A, -b]`

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Hi Louis, is this not a good answer already to a question?

Comment: Jokeur, I wouldn't worry about that comment. That's a boilerplate welcome to the site for first time *question*-writers. @Louis must have mistakenly positioned it on your answer. You can safely disregard it. Additionally, in order for the system to notify another user that you answered their comment, you should include @+their username, like I did above. Otherwise people have no way of knowing that you have replied to their comments.

Comment: OK, thanks @MarcoB. I am not new to Mathematica, but still getting hang of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Also, are you the same user that wrote [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/110688/27951)? If so, you may have two duplicate unregistered accounts. You should register for the site and merge the two accounts (and reputation!) as explained here: [How to merge accidentally created accounts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @Jokeur Thanks for the answer. But when I do that and then put in i1-i2, I still get the same thing as before. I don't get some result. Just the input returned as is.